# Eclipse DevStyle change to original eclipse oxygen

Tags: java, eclipse

I got a message from eclipse, which contains that i can try DevStyle. It's not run my projects so i want back the eclipse oxygen run like before, how can i use the original eclipse? When i change workspace i got the following message: Specified path is invalid, it's worked before i accepted devstyle. My workspace parent folder contains dot character maybe it's the problem, i think it's not a normal behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dot caused the problem, if you have dot in your workspace path it's not work, but the start page you can turn of the DevStyle.